# What is this Northern British location in the opening scene of West is West?

Tags: film-location, west-is-west

In [West is West](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Is_West_(2010_film)), the 2010 sequel to Ayub Khan Din's [East is East](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Is_East_(1999_film)), the opening shot is a long-shot of a Northern British town's alleyway (don't think it can be considered a gennel?):

[image]

Is there any more information on where *exactly* this particular shot takes place? If not, is at least the rough location of it known?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the back of Silverdale Street, Manchester - now demolished & a new estate built.

[Google streets view of it in 2012](https://www.google.com/maps/@53.4739095,-2.1574343,3a,75y,267.17h,66.14t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s9pp2JiWh6jDcXavgt4U56A!2e0!7i13312!8i6656) - open space, but this is probably within a few yards of it, the cobbles are all that remain, if you look away from the road, across the grass, to East or West

Source: [British Film Locations - West is West](http://www.british-film-locations.com/West-Is-West-2010)

[image]

That type of terraced housing would very frequently back onto such small back streets - it's all very *Coronation Street* ;)
btw, this wouldn't qualify as a **ginnel**, it's simply a 'back street'. A ginnel would be smaller, usually just wide enough for one or two people walking.

*Late edit*
Using Google's street view history, I've found the chippy, corner of [Silverdale & Toxteth](https://www.google.com/maps/@53.4732962,-2.1569562,3a,75y,348.71h,92.13t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s2HoW2APOyYMW2l595dDRSQ!2e0!7i13312!8i6656)

[image]

The shot *may* be directly behind the chippy, but Google didn't capture a good shot of it from either end. [This is the closest we'll probably ever get.](https://www.google.com/maps/@53.4732993,-2.1571234,3a,75y,347.56h,83.96t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1sRhWih-Sx2bY2DO5_Wc6GwQ!2e0!5s20090601T000000!7i13312!8i6656)

[image]

This is it today…

[image]

Comment: agreed, it SCREAMS Coronation St https://coronationstreet.fandom.com/wiki/Title_sequence - scroll down to the colour ones

Comment: So you're saying that this was at the back of the chippie?

Comment: As it's all gone now, it's kind of hard to prove. I added more pics.

Comment: Great detective work, thank you. Kinda sad to see it's all gone, I've always liked those back alleys.